# Having trouble accessing Object element with a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable "session" that is passed from a different function. 
I am not sure how to format it so that I can use it as follows:

```
passed to function  - // session  = 'coverType_1' )

var tag = session.substring(session.indexOf("_") + 1);

document.write(dataBlock['coverType_'+tag]['coverage'][1]);
```

this displays as "undefined"...

As a comparison, however, this works:

```
var i = 1;

document.write(dataBlock['coverType_'+i]['coverage'][1]);
```

How can I format "session" to use as a variable for this Object element.

I assume "session" has lost it's scope from the other function, as it works within the previous function.

Thanks in advance. This has thrown me off for about a week.

Comment: Not enough code. Try a jsfiddle.

Comment: Do a `console.log(tag)` before `document.write` to see if you have the right value for your `tag` variable. If that is not ok, try the same with `session`, maybe you didn't pass it to the scope.

Comment: We will need to know more about the structure of the code in order to make any kind of diagnosis, or you'll get "answers" which are actually just guessing at what the problem is. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be getting the right `tag`, or the `dataBlock` object.

Instead of doing `var tag = session.substring(session.indexOf("_") + 1);`,
use `split()` operator:

```
var tag = session.split("_")[1];
```

Next, I am not sure if you meant to use your `dataBlock` as a 3-D array, but if you did, be very careful as you're handling a lot of data inside it. I would recommend using `console.log(dataBlock['coverType_'+tag])` first, 
then `console.log(dataBlock['coverType_'+tag]['coverType_'+tag])` 
to verify if it has the data you need. If not, the "other function" giving the dataBlock object is broken.

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies to my admittingly vague question. I was able to resolve my problem and, as you suggested,  the array was broken.